# node mysql checking and updating foreach loop

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a foreach loop in which I connect to the mysql database select a unique value from table "A" return that value then insert and update the row in table "A" based on if this value exists. The problem I have is that it seems the asynchronous qualities of node JS / javascript mean that when I loop back round and again look in table "A" for that value it sometimes does not exist because the previous loop has not performed the insert in time. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Simple, don't use a forEach loop. Use a function that calls itself with the next record to loop over instead.

Comment: do you mind explaining this in more detail please

Comment: In other words, don't continue the loop until the previous db request has completed since each subsequent iteration requires the previous to be complete.

Comment: thanks if you make this an answer ill mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since in your case you need the previous db query to finish before the next, you'll have to stop using your forEach loop and instead use a recursive function.

```
var testArr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

function doWork (i) {
    if (i === testArr.length) return;
    db.doQuery('foobar with ' + testArr[i] + '...', function () {
        doWork(i++);
    });
}
doWork(0);
```